# Template for Wedding Order of Service?

Tags: lyx, templates

I'm trying furiously to design an Order of Service for a wedding in Latex (wedding is tomorrow...lol). I'm also using Lyx to hopefully speed things up.

First off, I can't seem to find a suitable document class, or any example templates online.

The closest I found was this guy:

http://boyinthebands.com/archives/feature-set-for-latex-order-of-worship-project/

who talks about doing it - but it seems he never got around to actually doing it in Latex.

Any ideas of a class/template that would work? Any suggestions at all would be great. (Right now I'm just using article.cls...)

An idea of what's on an Order of Service:

http://docs-eu.livesiteadmin.com/bf230ef6-82c4-403d-830a-ec9be6b38e19/wedding-order-of-service-template.pdf

For ornamental fonts, I was thinking of using adforn or fourier-orns - however, I have no idea to do this from within Lyx?

Even the title I'm struggling with...lol. In Latex, I'd use \ to separate - in Lyx, Alt-Return does the same. However, then the lines of the title are too close. I tried changing the line spacing to double, however, it still appears to render exactly the same, with the lines too close:

```
\begin{doublespace}

\title{The Marriage of\\
Foo Bar\\
to\\
Foo Bar}
\end{doublespace}

\maketitle
```

Finally, for the songs, I'd need something like:'

```
Name of song..........Composer/Artist
```

The Composer/Artist should be right-aligned, and there should be an appropriate number of "..." separating - what's the easiest way to achieve that in Lyx/Latex? I don't even know what the above is called, typesetting wise, so I couldn't Google it.

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: There’s an example of this sort of thing in Italian at http://www.guitex.org/home/en/forum/5-tex-e-latex/42830-libretto-messa

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. `\\[1cm]` to add more space when using `\\`. I guess the `doublespace` environment doesn't do anything because `\title` doesn't actually typeset anything, it is `\maketitle` that typesets the content of `\title`, `\author` and `\date`.

For LyX: To insert some vertical space you can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then do Insert --> Formatting --> Vertical space.

For the songs you could `\dotfill` in an ERT. Write the name of the song, insert an ERT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) and write `\dotfill` (with a space after) in it, move the cursor outside the ERT, and write the composer.

For e.g. `adforn` go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add

```
\usepackage{adforn}
```

To use the different commands described in [the `adforn` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/adforn), just insert an ERT and write them in that.

Comment: Thanks for that =). I'm trying those suggestions now. For the first one (paragraph spacing) - if I just put "Enter" between each paragraph, and they're set as `Title`, it only shows the last line (e.g. "Foo Bar"). Likewise if I use an ERT (Ctrl-L) with `[\\[1cm]`, it only displays the last line of the title. If I use Alt+Return, it shows all the lines, however, inserting either a vertical space, or that ERT doesn't seem to have any effect?

Comment: @victorhooi You can only have one title, hitting enter "exits" the title you're writing. You can add `\\[1cm]` in a title, just don't hit enter before or after the ERT. On the other hand, you don't really have to use title at all, you could just write the text in standard mode and format it as you like (center aligned paragraph, large text, etc. Select the text, right click --> Text style for size etc., right click Paragraph settings to center align. I'm afraid I really have to go to bed now, good luck!